# Difference in days between today and unix timestamp..

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp, datediff

So first things first is DateDiff() the way to go?

```
<?php

$date1 = strtotime(1766253900); // expiry date
$date2 = strtotime(1539652560); // todays date
$dtDiff = $date1 - $date2;
$totalDays = intval($dtDiff/(24*60*60));
echo $totalDays
?>
```

I tried it this way but it is outputting 0 ZERO

Comment: There's no need to put the timestamps in strtotime, just subtract one timestamp from another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove strtotime as both dates are already UNIX timestamps i.e. number of seconds since 1970

```
<?php

$date1 = 1766253900; // expiry date
$date2 = 1539652560; // todays date
$dtDiff = $date1 - $date2;
$totalDays = intval($dtDiff/(24*60*60));
echo $totalDays
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do this using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) classes:

```
// set expiry date
$date1 = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp(1766253900);
// today's date
$date2 = new DateTime();
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $diff->days;
```

Output (as of 15/10/2018)

```
2622
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you input the 1766253900 and 1539652560 are already timestamps, the strotime function is make the normal date transform the UNIX time, so you needn't use strotime convert the UNIX time to UNIX time

```
<?php
$date1 = 1766253900; //expiry date
$date2 = 1539652560; //todays date
$totalDays = intval(($date1-$date2)/(24*60*60));
print_r($totalDays);
```

you can use mysql function convert UNIX time to normal time

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1766253900); #2025-12-21 02:05:00
```

but also you can use mysql function convert normal time to UNIX time

```
mysql> select unix_timestamp('2025-12-21 02:05:00'); #1766253900
```